# What is the name of this flower with purple leaves and orange inner part in NYC?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I've photographed this flower a few days ago in New York City:

[image]

Does anybody know the name of it? (and how is the orange part called?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[It's Echinacea.](http://oglesbytc.com/catalog/patio-and-garden/echinacea/echinacea-prairie-splendor.html) I've linked to one site but if you run an images search with Echinacea as the search term you'll see lots of examples.

[And here is the WP page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinacea)

Supplementary

Echinacea are members of the [Compositae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositae). The flower (the **head**) in your picture is actually made up of lots of individual smaller flowers (i.e. it is a *composite* flower). The petals are formed by **ray flowers**, and the central part, the *disc* is made up of **disc flowers**. More details at the WP page I have linked to for Compositae.

Comment: And how is the orange part called?

Comment: @moose it is the head inflorescence which consists of ray florets and disk florets

Comment: @moose it is not a flower actually but an inflorescence which resembles like a flower. ray florets in general are situated at the peripheral parts of inflorescence and disk florets are situated in the centre which is a unique feature of asteraceae (other name for compositae)

Comment: @moose ray florets are the female flowers and disk florets are the bisexual flowers

Comment: The first link is dead.